# BigQuery 'get_client' package missing/not importable on Python 3 (to export a schema)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, schema

Edit: I have BigQuery-Python, bigQueryExporter, and google-cloud-bigquery installed already so that's not the issue.

I am trying to export the schema of an existing BQ table, including all the nested fields. To do this, I am attempting to import BQ's 'get_client' package, but it doesn't seem to exist for python3 (or perhaps it has changed).

My first attempt at creating the schema was successful but did not tackle the nested fields that I need (see below):

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


def test_extract_schema():

    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('file')
    project = 'project_id'
    dataset_id = 'test1'
    table_id = 'testc'

    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API Request

    result = {schema.name: schema.field_type for schema in table.schema}
    listresult = [result]

    print(listresult)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_extract_schema()
```

My current version, one that I'm not sure will work even if I get the package to run, looks like this:

```py
import web
from google.cloud import bigquery
from bigquery import get_client


urls = ('/GetFields(.*)', 'get_Fields')
app = web.application(urls, globals())


def get():

    project_id = 'project_id'
    dataset_id = 'test1'
    table_id = 'testc'

    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('file')

    results = client.get_table_schema(dataset_id, table_id)

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get()
```

"get_table_schema" is not recognized because the get_client package cannot be installed. Is this not available for Python 3, or is there some other issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem!

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


def get_table_schema():

    project_id = 'project_id'
    dataset_id = 'test1'
    table_id = 'testc'

    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('file')

    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    bq_tableref = bigquery.table.TableReference(dataset_ref, table_id)
    bq_table = bigquery_client.get_table(bq_tableref)

    schema = [i.to_api_repr() for i in bq_table.schema]

    print('schema is ', schema)

    return schema


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_table_schema()
```